# Arcpy to signal a portion/segment of a line on ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.2. I have an attribute table with many rows and I want to signal only one of this rows on map. What is the function of ArcMap that allows to do this automatically with arcpy?

Answer (score 1):

If by *signaling* we're referring to the *display* of only one specific feature from your attribute table on the map, then using ArcPy this can be handled by the `definitionQuery` property of the associated Layer's [Layer Object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm).

Specifying a definition query in ArcPy would look something like this:

```
import arcpy

Query_Attribute = "Item_No"
Query_Value = 150

my_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Path\\To\\My\\Feature Class")
my_layer.definitionQuery = Query_Attribute + " = " + str(Query_Value)
```

Refreshing the map display should reflect the change in the definiton query.

Comment: I did this but it didn't anything... It doesn´t display